# Deploying to Snapshots Local not found in Snapshots

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

We use Jenkins to deploy to Artifactory, and seeing the output when running the build like

```
[main] INFO org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoClientBuilder - Deploying artifact: https://artifactory.my-company.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/awgtek/services/my-awesome-service/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/my-awesome-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Shortly after this I try to run a build of another project that depends on this, and it fails.
I checked the repository settings in the pom of the dependent project and it has:

```
        <repository>
            <snapshots/>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>libs-snapshot</name>
            <url>https://artifactory.my-company.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
```

My question is what is the best practice with regard to adding a new repository here, namely, "`libs-snapshot-local`" since as can be seen above it's deploying to "`libs-snapshot-local`" but not "`libs-snapshot`". If not, as I understand it libs-snapshot should somehow resolve jars in libs-snapshot-local, but in this case that is not working. Is there a wait period for caches to refresh? Or should I just go ahead and add "libs-snapshot-local" to my dependent project's pom.xml repositories element?

Comment: Have you run the build with `-U` ?

Comment: no. Is `-U` the solution then? If so I will try next time this issue occurs. For now, it appears the problem resolved itself after some time, so the issue must have been only temporary.

Comment: `-U` updates your local repository immediately.